# implementing transaction scope

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

While implementing transaction scope in mvc application. is it better to create a transaction manager while calling the wcf service.  or is it better to have the transactionscope within the business object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally go for separation of concerns. Business object has nothing to do with transaction scope, so i'd vote for transaction manager (if it's a big application) or combine it with your DAL (if it's not that modular/big).

Comment: if you have WCF service, would you wrap in transaction while the client proxy calling the service?

Comment: It depends on your particular problem. If there's the need to lock for data access, atomic execution and data is critical - then yes. If there are only simple select queries then there's no need to.